# MEX/Matlab: Accessing objectarray which is a member of another object

Tags: c, matlab, oop, mex

I have the following Matlab "Class-Design":

```
classdef foo
    properties
        a;
        b;
    end

    methods
        function obj = myFun(obj)
            obj.a = 42; // some calculation takes place here
        end
    end
end

classdef bar
    properties
        foos; // this is going to be an array of foos
        otherStuff;
    end

    methods
        function obj = someFun(obj)
            for i = 1:length(foos)
                obj.foos(i) = obj.foos(i).myFun;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As I wrote, one object will have an array of other objects as its class properties.

I am trying to rewrite this as a C code and use it with MEX. My question now is: How can I access the different elements of the array foos?
I know of the API-function mxGetProperty. With this function I am able to access the properties of each of the array entries (e.g. obj.foos(i).a), but not the object as a whole (I want to have obj.foos(i) ). However, I need the whole object (as an mxArray *) in order to call the member function.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: there is no direct MEX function to extract an element of an object array. You could write a helper function in MATLAB to do so, and call this function instead from you MEX-function.

Answer (score 0):

After calling mxGetProperty to get array of objects it is better to call into MATLAB to do the indexing on this array of objects. If bar_mx is the mxArray for bar object then

```
 foos_prop = mxGetProperty(bar_mx, 0, "foos"); // Gives foos property
 foos_i = mexCallMATLAB( ... [foos_prop, i]) call MATLAB function to get i'th foo
```

You can combine your call to get i'th object along with calling of a method on that object. If you want to do the indexing in C++ you may need to call [subsref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) function. It is easier to do mexCallMATLAB instead of creating the struct argument for subsref.